# excel replace values of multiple rows

Tags: excel

I have an excel-question that i so-far haven't found a solution to.

Say i have for instance two columns **date** and **name**

the data could be something like

**date   |          name** 
02-05-1996 | smith 
02-06-1996 | johnson 
07-09-1996 | griffin 
02-08-2001 | carlsen 
17-11-2001 | petersen

and i want to change the values in the date-column so it is only the year that is left - like this:

**date   |          name** 
1996 | smith 
1996 | johnson 
1996 | griffin 
2001 | carlsen 
2001 | petersen

how could you do this?

Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: Do you want it to be done using code? Is this a 1-time operation? Is it OK if the cell contains the date, but the displayed part shows Year (using cell-format)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that the dates start from A1, select C1 and type `=Year(A1)` and copy it down to fill the full range.

If you want to get rid of the old dates, select the range just created with the years, cut it, select the original range with the full dates, paste only values.

Comment: @nnnn7993 After you enter the formula, click on the cell and note the black square at the bottom-right corner. Double click that square and the formula will be copied down the worksheet to the last active row.

Comment: Press `Shift+Ctrl+End` to select from the current cell to the last cell of the sheet, or `Shift+Ctrl+Down` to select from the current cell to the last cell of the current column (it works only if the column already has values, otherwise you can start from the bottom and press `Shift+Ctrl+Up`. To copy the first cell to all the cell of a range select the range and press `Ctrl+D` (as in down) or `Ctrl+R`  (as in right).

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is the YEAR() function

http://office.microsoft.com/en-ca/excel-help/year-HP005209343.aspx?CTT=5&origin=HP005204211

Assuming your date column is A

```
= year(A1)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
option explicit
Sub ChangeDateValuesToYear(ByVal startCell As Range)
Dim cell

Dim lastCellInThisColumn As Range
Set lastCellInThisColumn = startCell.End(xlDown)

Dim dateDataRange As Range
Set dateDataRange = Range(startCell, lastCellInThisColumn)

For Each cell In dateDataRange
    cell.Value = Year(cell.Value)
Next

dateDataRange.NumberFormat = 0
End Sub
```

EDIT: Assuming the cell for dates is in column `A`, starting from `A1`, you can do the following

`call ChangeDateValuesToYear(Range("A1"))`